# Granted, the plastic envelopes that encase computer components challenge the most avid box shredder. - I don't understand what this sentence says

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself Networking in 24 Hours, 4th Edition by Uyless Black (2009)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0768685761)

Example:

> If you're opening the case and the top doesn't come off easily, don't force it. Forcing a computer case may damage the box and its contents. **Granted, the plastic envelopes that encase computer components** (and other modern electronic products) **challenge the most avid box shredder**. Nonetheless, force will merely strengthen the case against you... so to speak.

I pondered what that might mean for a while and finally gave up. Any idea as to what exactly the author means by plastic envelops and avid box shredder? What does all that have to do with shredding cases made of plastic? I don't understand the joke.

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the adjective _avid?_

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the word "avid" is definitely not used when describing things. You use it only to talk about people.

Comment: In your citation, _box shredder_ **does** refer to a person: "the most avid person who shreds boxes." cf. "milk drinker", "dog walker", "meat eater".

Comment: _"...the plastic envelopes that encase computer components ... challenge the most avid box shredder"_ means "plastic blister packs are difficult to open even for a person who is good at opening packages." But there really isn't supposed to be a "joke" there.

Comment: It means that the writer's boredom caught up with him when he came to penning that part of his text and he was, understandably,  looking for an amusing diversion. It's meagre fare for such drudgery, but needs must, as they say. I've done worse.

Comment: I think the author is trying to be witty (cf. "strengthen the case"). Even though the plastic envelopes will give the components inside some protection from a person who likes to tear a box apart when opening it, you should open it carefully.  "avid box shredder" is a kenning for "clumsy oaf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason it might be confusing is that the author is trying to be funny by calling it an *avid* box-shredder.  "Avid" is more frequently a term used with humans, meaning "keen interest" or "enthusiasm".

> He is an avid student of English

When you apply *avid* to an inanimate object it becomes a metaphor, so we can imagine this shredder *eagerly* chewing up everything it can -- but *choking* on the tough plastic packaging that computer components come in.